# Проблема позиционирование картинки и блоков

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть картинка и блоки которые должны как бы косаться этой линии, если сделать на одной ширине и все подогнать минусовыми margin то норм, но на больших экранах оно ломается потому что картинка(эта линия) растягивается и уже нужно задавать другие отступы. Как сделать что бы все было норм на всех разрешениях ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.quarters{
 min-height: 800px;
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ypWz.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 padding: 200px 0 0 0;
}
.line_quarters{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.block_querters_borders{
    height: 260px;
    border-left: 2px solid #34cb4d;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.block_querters_borders:nth-of-type(2){
  margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}
.block_querters_borders:&:last-child{
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.first_text_quarters{
  width: 184px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #34cb4d;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.first_text_quarters h2{
  font-family: "Jura";
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #131314;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.block_querters_borders ul{
  margin-top: 20px;
}     
.block_querters_borders ul li{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Jura";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 16px;
} 
.block_querters_borders ul li:before,{
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 27px 1px rgba(37, 235, 70, 0.61);
  background: #34cb4d;
  content:"";
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px 15px 0 0;
}
.line{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.line_quarters_bottom{
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.bottom_querters_borders{
  height: 280px;
  border-left: 2px solid #34cb4d;
  margin-right: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}     
.bottom_querters_borders:last-child{
  height:150px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.two_text_quarters{
  width: 184px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #34cb4d;
} 
.two_text_quarters h2{
  font-family: "Jura";
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #131314;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.two_text_quarters ul{
    margin-top: 20px;
}  
.two_text_quarters ul li{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Jura";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 16px;
}  
.two_text_quarters ul li:before,{
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 27px 1px rgba(37, 235, 70, 0.61);
  background: #34cb4d;
  content:"";
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:10px 15px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <title>Watt</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <section class="quarters container-fluid " id="quarters">
   <div class="row line_quarters justify-content-center">
    <div class="block_querters_borders">
     <div class="first_text_quarters">
      <h2>II квартал 2018</h2>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>
       consectetur adipisicing elit,
      </li>
      <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
      <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="block_querters_borders">
     <div class="first_text_quarters">
      <h2>IV квартал 2018</h2>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>consectetur adipisicing elit,</li>
      <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
      <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="block_querters_borders">
     <div class="first_text_quarters">
      <h2>I квартал 2019</h2>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
      <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row line justify-content-center">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TW9k.png" alt="line">
   </div>
   <div class="row line_quarters_bottom justify-content-center">
    <div class="bottom_querters_borders">
     <div class="two_text_quarters">
      <h2>III квартал 2018</h2>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
      <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
      <li>ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
      <li>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
       consectetur adipisicing elit,
      </li>
      <li>sed do eiusmod tempor incididun</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom_querters_borders">
     <div class="two_text_quarters">
      <h2>II квартал 2019</h2>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li>
       sed do eiusmod tempor incididun, <br>  
       consectetur adipisicing elit,
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Не растягивать картинку, сами блоки (от куда идут линии) делать на position absolute, к самому контейнеру добавить position relative, а дальше блоки в зависимости от расширения экрана двигать с помощью top, right, bottom и left

Comment: А вы разделите: фоновая картинка(часы) в родительский блок, а линию- в дочерний блок с контентом. Для дочернего: `max-width` и центрировать `margin:auto`. Ну и ваш код приведите, с большей вероятностью помогут.

Comment: самое лёгкое здесь будет SVG

Answer (score 0):

Для верхних блоков

```
margin-top: auto;
```

Для нижних блоков

```
margin-bottom: auto;
```

Comment: и что изменится?

Comment: Вместо того чтобы писать уже бы проверили

Comment: ничего не меняется